# Exchange data simultaneously between mobile devices via NFC

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, nfc

**Background**

I would like to achieve a peer-to-peer connection to transmit data between two mobile devices. The amount of data to be transmitted would be around 70-200 bytes, so it is quite small. This transmission also won't be some stream-like continuous flow. It would be a one-time thing to get the acknowledgement of the devices.

**TL;DR**: I want to exchange data between 2 mobile phones which would be using the same app.

**Requirements**

- Has to work offline
- Has to work between IOS & Android

**So Far**

I have analyzed a few possible ways to achieve that and I am quite confused about what to pick.

- NFC: I want to simultaneously send data for both phones and NFC does not work as a tag in the IOS. If there is a workaround for that let me know.
- NFC + BLE: This approach utilizes the NFC to pair devices to use Bluetooth then the data transfer is conducted on BLE.

So, I'm humbly asking a direction about getting my head around those concepts to solve my problem. If you have another technology that might help me, please specify it. Also, I'm making the development with React Native.